# Fresh install of Delphi community edition, new empty app crashes on launch

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have just downloaded and installed Delphi community edition, Version 28.0.48361.3236. I chose File/New/Windows VCL Application - Delphi. I made absolutely no changes to the code, and ran it. I was prompter to save the form and then project, then got

[image]

When I click "Details",  I see

```
[7B213A44]{coreide280.bpl} SourceModule.TSourceBuffers.GetItemCount (Line 343, "SourceModule.pas" + 0) + $0
[7B214FDF]{coreide280.bpl} SourceModule.TSourceModule.GetSourceBufferCount (Line 853, "SourceModule.pas" + 0) + $3
[7B216877]{coreide280.bpl} SourceModule.TCodeISourceModule.GetModuleFileCount (Line 1357, "SourceModule.pas" + 1) + $3
[7A05F8AD]{vcldesigner280.bpl} VCLFormContainer.TCommonFormHostWrapper.GetSourceEditor (Line 1251, "VCLFormContainer.pas" + 2) + $8
[7A05F94F]{vcldesigner280.bpl} VCLFormContainer.TCommonFormHostWrapper.GetVisible (Line 1261, "VCLFormContainer.pas" + 1) + $5
[7A06546B]{vcldesigner280.bpl} VCLFormDesigner.TVCLRootDesigner.DesignerHide (Line 554, "VCLFormDesigner.pas" + 3) + $8
[777871E9]{designide280.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentDesigner.HideWindows (Line 6971, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 6) + $5
[77789D83]{designide280.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TDesigners.HideWindows (Line 7791, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 2) + $8
[77789D58]{designide280.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TDesigners.HideDesignWindows (Line 7783, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 0) + $0
[7773AFB5]{designide280.bpl} Events.TEvent.Send (Line 154, "Events.pas" + 2) + $11
[777AC19B]{designide280.bpl} DeskUtil.HideDesignForms (Line 693, "DeskUtil.pas" + 30) + $7
[000FBA95]{bds.exe     } AppMain.TAppBuilder.HideWindows (Line 4181, "AppMain.pas" + 9) + $0
[000FC955]{bds.exe     } AppMain.TAppBuilder.ProcessStarted (Line 4378, "AppMain.pas" + 2) + $2
[7B3B5347]{coreide280.bpl} DebuggerMgr.TDebuggerMgr.ProcessStateChanged (Line 2613, "DebuggerMgr.pas" + 7) + $11
[1046696E]{dbkdebugide280.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.DoNotifyProcessStateChanged (Line 11451, "Debug.pas" + 2) + $18
[7775CEC3]{designide280.bpl} ToolUtils.ForEach (Line 116, "ToolUtils.pas" + 9) + $F
[104668CD]{dbkdebugide280.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.NotifyProcessStateChanged (Line 11443, "Debug.pas" + 27) + $22
[104616A9]{dbkdebugide280.bpl} Debug.TProcess.EvaluatorBusy (Line 8957, "Debug.pas" + 10) + $10
[10462E36]{dbkdebugide280.bpl} Debug.TProcess.SetProcessState (Line 9744, "Debug.pas" + 4) + $A
[1045B9EF]{dbkdebugide280.bpl} Debug.TThread.ntfyThread (Line 6319, "Debug.pas" + 11) + $2
[786B8D0C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 39031, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[786B8D1D]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@IntfCopy (Line 39078, "System.pas" + 6) + $0
[104617F8]{dbkdebugide280.bpl} Debug.TProcess.ntfyNewThread (Line 9022, "Debug.pas" + 8) + $F
[355560AB]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2B233
[7AD468B3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.HandleMessage (Line 7401, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 3) + $6
[7AE6AE92]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TStyleEngine.HandleMessage (Line 3610, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 22) + $7
[7AD43338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[7AC46749]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TDockTree.WndProc (Line 16437, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 75) + $5
[7AC3B1D3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage (Line 9462, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $F
[7AC3CAFB]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlActivateMsg (Line 10438, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 16) + $1D
[7AC3D1F5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10644, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 170) + $6
[7ADFF047]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.CaptionedDockTree.TCaptionedDockTree.WndProc (Line 264, "Vcl.CaptionedDockTree.pas" + 28) + $0
[7AC4600A]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TDockTree.WindowProc (Line 16180, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $2
[7AC37C64]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7369, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[7AC40391]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate (Line 12731, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $13
[7AC3802E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7591, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[786B0B24]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Destroy (Line 19911, "System.pas" + 0) + $0
[786B4B37]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 33214, "System.pas" + 72) + $2
[7AD43119]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.GetStyle (Line 5803, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 7) + $D
[786B18FC]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@TryFinallyExit (Line 23757, "System.pas" + 8) + $0
[7AD43207]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.GetStyle (Line 5814, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 18) + $1E
[786B0683]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TObject.Dispatch (Line 19228, "System.pas" + 11) + $0
[7AD470E5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.WndProc (Line 7713, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 38) + $6
[7AD472C6]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TMouseTrackControlStyleHook.WndProc (Line 7812, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 1) + $4
[7AD92E44]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook.WndProc (Line 18427, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 16) + $5
[7AE6A5DF]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TCustomStyle.SourceLoaded (Line 3313, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 1) + $F
[7AD4690A]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.HandleMessage (Line 7418, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 20) + $6
[7AD8E8A3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook.IsStyleBorder (Line 16547, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $C
[7AD8E8E4]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook.HandleMessage (Line 16554, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 2) + $6
[7AE6AE92]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TStyleEngine.HandleMessage (Line 3610, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 22) + $7
[7AD43338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[7AC3B1D3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage (Line 9462, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $F
[7AC3D1F5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10644, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 170) + $6
[7AD43338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[35532172]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $72FA
[7AC37C64]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7369, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[7AC40391]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate (Line 12731, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $13
[7AC3802E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7591, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[3554C670]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $217F8
[3554C657]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $217DF
[35538672]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $D7FA
[7AC3B1D3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage (Line 9462, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $F
[7AC3D1F5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10644, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 170) + $6
[3552EDA6]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $3F2E
[3554BCFB]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $20E83
[3554BF95]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2111D
[3554D831]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $229B9
[787263CE]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Generics.Defaults.Equals_Class (Line 1138, "System.Generics.Defaults.pas" + 1) + $6
[7AE70F73]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.{System.Generics.Collections}TDictionary<System.Classes.TComponent,Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook>.GetBucketIndex (Line 7098, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 16) + $15
[7AD190E5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanelStyleHook.AcceptMessage (Line 12489, "Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas" + 1) + $2
[7AD468B3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.HandleMessage (Line 7401, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 3) + $6
[7AE6AE92]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TStyleEngine.HandleMessage (Line 3610, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 22) + $7
[7AD43338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[7AC3B1D3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage (Line 9462, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $F
[7AC3D1F5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10644, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 170) + $6
[786B3CE5]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@UStrDelete (Line 31958, "System.pas" + 10) + $5
[786AA3B0]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 4997, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[786B2424]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@UStrClr (Line 26225, "System.pas" + 14) + $0
[787AC88C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.TStrings.GetValueFromIndex (Line 7424, "System.Classes.pas" + 12) + $10
[7AC37C64]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7369, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[7AC40391]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate (Line 12731, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $13
[7AC3802E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7591, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[3552EDA6]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $3F2E
[3554D177]{bordbk280N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $222FF
[7AC40391]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate (Line 12731, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $13
[7AC3802E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7591, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[786B8D0C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 39031, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[786B4B78]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 33223, "System.pas" + 81) + $2
[786B0B24]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Destroy (Line 19911, "System.pas" + 0) + $0
[786B0279]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TObject.CleanupInstance (Line 18614, "System.pas" + 23) + $0
[786AA3B0]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 4997, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[786B00A8]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TObject.FreeInstance (Line 18315, "System.pas" + 2) + $2
[786B086E]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@ClassDestroy (Line 19678, "System.pas" + 0) + $2
[7B344EC0]{coreide280.bpl} CodeEditorServices.TCodeEditorPaintContext.Destroy (Line 1218, "CodeEditorServices.pas" + 3) + $6
[7C18F62E]{boreditu.dll} C:\PROJECTS\OLYMPUS\TP\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\CW32.LIB|_fastmm.@_FastMM_FinalizeMemoryManager + $4E
[7C18DBF3]{boreditu.dll} C:\PROJECTS\OLYMPUS\TP\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\CW32.LIB|wiostrea.@std@%basic_filebuf$b19std@%char_traits$b%%@imbue$qrx10std@locale + $42F
[787263CE]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Generics.Defaults.Equals_Class (Line 1138, "System.Generics.Defaults.pas" + 1) + $6
[7AE70F73]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.{System.Generics.Collections}TDictionary<System.Classes.TComponent,Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook>.GetBucketIndex (Line 7098, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 16) + $15
[787263CE]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Generics.Defaults.Equals_Class (Line 1138, "System.Generics.Defaults.pas" + 1) + $6
[7AE70F73]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.{System.Generics.Collections}TDictionary<System.Classes.TComponent,Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook>.GetBucketIndex (Line 7098, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 16) + $15
[786E41CB]{rtl280.bpl  } System.SysUtils.AnsiCompareText (Line 7240, "System.SysUtils.pas" + 1) + $2F
[786B0B24]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Destroy (Line 19911, "System.pas" + 0) + $0
[786B4B37]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 33214, "System.pas" + 72) + $2
[7AD43119]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.GetStyle (Line 5803, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 7) + $D
[786B18FC]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@TryFinallyExit (Line 23757, "System.pas" + 8) + $0
[7AD43207]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.GetStyle (Line 5814, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 18) + $1E
[7AC39B2E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.GetStyleName (Line 8631, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 5) + $7
[7AE6A5DF]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TCustomStyle.SourceLoaded (Line 3313, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 1) + $F
[7AE6A51C]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TCustomStyle.GetEnabled (Line 3293, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 0) + $0
[7AD3C00F]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.StyleServices (Line 2327, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 12) + $8
[7AD3C075]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.StyleServices (Line 2341, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 26) + $10
[7AE6A5DF]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TCustomStyle.SourceLoaded (Line 3313, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 1) + $F
[7AE6A51C]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TCustomStyle.GetEnabled (Line 3293, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 0) + $0
[7AC403CA]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate (Line 12737, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 9) + $2
[7AC3802E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7591, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[7AD4C8BD]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.{System.Generics.Collections}TDictionary<System.TClass,System.Generics.Collections.TList<Vcl.Themes.TStyleHookClass>>.ContainsKey (Line 7467, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 1) + $F
[7AE6AE2E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TStyleEngine.HandleMessage (Line 3596, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 8) + $9
[7AD43338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[7AC3B1D3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage (Line 9462, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $F
[7AC3D1F5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10644, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 170) + $6
[7B526AEE]{coreide280.bpl} StructureView.TBaseStructureViewServices.StructureChanged (Line 675, "StructureView.pas" + 2) + $29
[786B4B37]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 33214, "System.pas" + 72) + $2
[786B4B25]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 33212, "System.pas" + 70) + $2
[786B4B6F]{rtl280.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 33222, "System.pas" + 80) + $4
[786B1107]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 20305, "System.pas" + 1) + $0
[786B0C4C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 19975, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[786B0AB4]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 19889, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[786B0DDA]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 20079, "System.pas" + 1) + $2
[787A9191]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.TThreadList.RemoveItem (Line 5563, "System.Classes.pas" + 5) + $6
[7AC183AC]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.TBitmapCanvas.FreeContext (Line 7413, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 12) + $3
[786B0AB4]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 19889, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[786B0DDA]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 20079, "System.pas" + 1) + $2
[786B0E36]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 20101, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[7AC1821D]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 7308, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 12) + $8
[7AC3C715]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 10324, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $0
[7AD8526B]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11490, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 25) + $1
[7AD852A6]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 11518, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[7AD855E5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 11657, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 27) + $3
[001480A2]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 227, "" + 16) + $2
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Is it your app or the IDE that crashes? Does your empty VCL app work just fine if you run it outside the debugger (Shift+Ctrl+F9)?

Comment: It runs just fine with Ctrl+Sgift+F9 (maybe I need to uninstall, then reinstall?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled & reinstalled and now it works.